# Algorithm to differentiate parts that are separated?

Tags: c#, connected-components

Let's say I have an image with some shapes on it.
Is there any algorithm that knows that there are multiple shapes on it, based on if they are separated or not?

[image: An example of my goal]

Comment: The thing you need is called “connected components labeling”, Wikipedia lists a few algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: You need to be clearer about when you are dealing with different holes: imagine the 2D-matrix "[[1,0][0,1]", where the zeroes only touch diagonally. Does this represent one hole or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an algorithm called "connected component labeling".
I used these intructions for the implementation:
https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-a-connected-component-labeling-algorithm-from-scratch-94e1636554f